# dojo1.8: Remotely load dojo page into content pane

Tags: dojo

I am able to load text or html page into the contentpane by request and href respectively.

However, I am not able to load dojo pages, ie dojo text or buttons into the contentpane.

Dojo files were parsed properly, when running directly in Firefox. However, they are not parsed properly inside contentpanes.

Please advise
 Thanks in advance.

Clement

Comment: can you add some code, so we can see what exactly you have tried?

Comment: Hi nozzlemen, see my link where you will find the code. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493506/dojo-1-8-loading-dojo-laced-htnl-files-into-contentpane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content loaded into a contentPane is not parsed for dojo widgets.  However, you can acheive this end by using [dojox/layout/contentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html).  The dojox version of the contentPane works in exactly the same way as the dijit version but allows for widget parsing.